# Can I use the ALJ D882 transistor or SS8550 transistor to control the 5V fan on my raspberry pi 3?

Tags: cooling

Can I use the ALJ D882 transistor or SS8550 transistor to control a 5V fan on my Raspberry Pi 3?

Fan is 5V 0.33A (fan from my old laptop).

http://alltransistors.com/transistor.php?transistor=52900 - D882

http://alltransistors.com/transistor.php?transistor=46094 - SS8550

Comment: Specs for these transistors? The Raspberry Pi does not have a 5V fan.  What fan are you talking about?  The actual fan specs will determine if it can be driven by a particular transistor.

Comment: I want to use a 5V 0.33A fan from my old laptop, actually i'm using it and it's working  but i want to control his speed

Comment: https://alltransistors.com/transistor.php?transistor=52900 - D882
https://alltransistors.com/transistor.php?transistor=46094 - SS8550